# Hospedagem para node.js

Tags: node.js, hospedagem

Bom dia, 
tenho 2 aplicações node.js com mongo, e precisava hospeda-las no mesmo lugar, uma aplicação gerencia a outra, utilizam o mesmo banco.
É possível coloca-las na mesma hospedagem, acessando uma aplicação pelo domínio adquirido, e a outra aplicação Admin, acessando tipo /admin?

Comment: Sim, é possível, existem várias clouds para hospedagem, uma com certas restrições mas gratuitas e facil de usar, como o Heroku, recomendo que estude sobre.

Comment: Ótimo Lucas Costa, obrigado!